# Getting thumbnails of a custom posts featured images in a page-templates metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I guess I need to know how to call meta data into metaboxes for beginners.

I'm using

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'   => 'slidertype',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
        )
    );
    //loop over each post
    foreach($posts as $p){
        //get the meta you need form each post
        $thumb = get_post_meta($p,"_thumbnail_id",true);

        echo $thumb;
```

To try to get thumbnails of my custom post type 'slidertype' to show up in a page's metabox. Right now it's displaying a number which doesn't make sense to me. No advice is bad advice guys! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the image from your $thumb integer with the following additional code:

```
$thumb = get_post_meta($p,"_thumbnail_id",true);
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb);
echo $image[0];
```

This will return the URL of the image, just put that in an img tag to display it.

Comment: Oh wow! I was so close but thanks so much. I'm trying to make a sortable list for my slider this way so I believe that I'll prob need the id's... Not sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) without having to first fetch the ID:

```
foreach( $posts as $p ){
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $p->ID, 'thumbnail' );
}
```

Or using [`setup_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) you can use template tags that only work "in the loop":

```
foreach( $posts as $p ){
    setup_postdata( $p );
    the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This is awesome. I wish I could vote you but I can't till lvl 15 sry.